# lighttpd 1.4.X - Error with reverse proxy - returns 0 byte - config or program error?

Tags: configuration, reverse-proxy, lighttpd

I have a setup where i need a proxy in front on a server. 
LightTpd 1.4.13 is already used on the embedded platform which should act as proxy.
Newer lighttpd's is not easily build due to an old toolchain.

One port (e.g. port 84) of the proxy platform should forward all traffic to port 80 on the server.

Some simple pages are forwarded just fine, but some other fail. The server has as "web_resp.exe", this is returned as a download option of 0 byte.

### Wireshark dumping

Dumps with Wireshark show that the needed pages are send the proxy-platform, but 0 bytes are forwarded. (this was performed on a similar setup)

### Question

1. Is my configuration wrong?
2. Is it impossible on lighttpd 1.4.13? (i have seen forum-post telling the mod_proxy of lighttpd has problem in general)

### Reproducibility

I have reproduced the flaw by running Lighttpd on a new mintLinux (same error type)
I get the same error when forwarding to other ip/site (a web-config of a ethernet -> rs232-port unit).

Exactly what triggers the error is do not know, maybee just too large pages.

### Configuration

```
#lighttpd configuration file
server.modules              = (
                           "mod_proxy"
    )

## a static document-root, for virtual-hosting take look at the
## server.virtual-* options
server.document-root        = "/tmp/"

## where to send error-messages to
server.errorlog             = "/tmp/lighttpd.error.log"

## bind to port (default: 80)
server.port                = 84

#### proxy module
## read proxy.txt for more info
proxy.debug                    = 1
proxy.server = ( "" =>
                   (    
            ( "host" => "10.0.0.175", "port" => 80)
           )
        )
```

### Debug dumps

functional and non-functional request seem similar.
However the non-functional read larger size of data (it is still to considered small size <100 kB)

### other tests

lighttpd 1.4.35 compiled for the target, but it seem to fail in same way.

lighttpd 1.4.35 neither work on the mintLinux.

1.4.35 + rewrite trick... 
works worse than directly using a port

lighttpd 1.5 works out of the box (after installing gthread2) on a mintLinux. However will not work for the target hardware.

Comment: I suspect the error might revolve around the `Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked` format. Try to download larger, but static files (no scripting). Those won't be chunked allowing you to confirm this. Making scripted output non-chunked can be tricky and you may have to give up compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue have been found to be faulty http headers provided by the backend.
The issue was submitted to the Lighttpd-bug site https://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2594#change-8877

Lighttpd now have support for webpages only sending \LF as opposed to \CR\LF

You may argue that the bug is in the target web-page. However in by case i was unable to modify the target site.